UK citizen with a US-born child. What visa if any does the child need to move to the UK?
I'm a British citizen and I've been in the US for 12 years now. I'm planning on moving back to the UK (leaving an abusive marriage). I have a place to stay in the UK with my dad.
I have a two-year-old US citizen child. I can't find anything on what my son needs to enter the UK and stay there permanently. He has a US passport. I had my husband's rights to my child terminated by the state.
But is my child of "British descent" as I'm British? I just can't find anything about my child needing a visa and I don't have that much time. I need to get home.
I can't afford a dependent visa for him. I've looked online and even though he is of British descent, it still said he needed a dependent visa?

The UK has a web page to see if a person is already a British citizen. It depends on the details of how the British citizen parent became a citizen. If the child is already a citizen, then you would apply for a British passport for the child.

"I've looked online and even though he is of British decent it still said he needed a dependency visa??": Can you link to the page that gives you this impression?  Then we will be more likely to identify whether you've misinterpreted it or if it is inapplicable to your son's circumstances, or if t's just wrong.  The phrase "of British descent" has no particular meaning in nationality law, but if he is a "British citizen" then he will most likely be a "British citizen by descent," meaning that his children won't acquire British citizenship automatically unless they're born in the UK.

I would also note that the UK has a fairly open policy toward British citizens entering the UK on foreign passports, so you won't necessarily need a British passport for your son (relevant to @GerardAshton's comment), since US citizens can enter the UK without visas.  If he's not a British citizen, he'd need a visa to stay in the UK, but if he is a British citizen, he can use a US passport as if he were a visitor and then just stay.  I mention this because of the time pressure you're under to move.

Are you a British citizen "otherwise than by descent"? ("by descent" means you were born outside the UK and got British citizenship from your parents. If you were born in the UK or naturalized in the UK, you would be a British citizen "otherwise than by descent".)

It’s all easiest if your son is a British citizen. “I am British” is half the story. You are either a British citizen by descent (by descent is less good), or, if you were born in the UK to at least one British parent then you are British citizen otherwise than by descent and your son is a British citizen by descent. If you were born outside the UK then you are a British citizen by descent and your son is not British -- unless your ex-husband is British otherwise than by descent then your son is British. He might not like that but there is no choice.

Birth in the UK is sufficient to be a British citizen otherwise than by descent; there is no requirement for a parent to be a British citizen.  Another way to become a British citizen otherwise than by descent is by naturalization.

There are large groups of people whose UK born children are UK citizens (example: Eu citizen with permanent leave to remain), but not all.

Correct, but all UK born British citizens are British citizens otherwise than by descent.  Therefore, the statement should be "if you were born in the UK then you are British citizen otherwise than by descent."  The nationality of the parents is not relevant.  Consider for example a British citizen who was born to foreign students who were not permanently settled in the UK.  Such a person does not acquire British citizenship at birth, but since we know she is a British citizen, we know that she must have been registered or naturalized, making her a British citizen otherwise than by descent.

By contrast, some British citizens who were born outside the UK are British citizens otherwise than by descent, namely those who did not acquire British citizenship by birth and those born of British parents who were abroad in Crown service).
